# Get ownProps.match.params.id in mapStateToProps from Redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom, react-props

Card component displays article data or note data.

I would like to move on to card details after click `Link` in `Card` component and show them in `Details` component, so I've used Redirect, as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Link from 'components/atoms/Link/Link';

class Card extends Component {
  state = { redirect: false };
  toggleButtonDetails = () => this.setState({ redirect: true });

  render() {
    const { _id, type } = this.props;
    const { redirect } = this.state;

    if (redirect) {
      return <Redirect push to={`/${type}/${_id}`} />;
    }

    return (
      <Link onClick={this.toggleButtonDetails}>See details</Link>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

It is important because I don't want to get details on the basis of URL sending `notes\:id` request or `articles\:id` request (ENTER in a browser) but from store where are many articles and notes.

So, I've decided to use `ownProps` in `mapStateToProps` in `Details` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const Details = ({ activeItem }) => {
  const [item] = activeItem;
  return (
    <>
      <p>{item.id}</p>
      <p>{item.type}</p>
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  activeItem: state[ownProps.type].filter(item => item._id === ownProps.match.params.id),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Details);
```

After click on the `Link` in `Card` I move to correct URL (`http://localhost:3000/notes/5d3c87034532003a6c666a67`, for example) but I have an error and I get `Cannot read property 'params' of undefined` in line with `activeItem: state[ownProps.type]...`.

When I used console.log(ownProps) in mapStateToProps I saw that `ownProps` contains only `type` without `id`.

When I changed `ownProps.match.params.id` to `'5d3c87034532003a6c666a67'` I saw correct note details but only one specified note - it's obvious but it means that **store works correct but I don't see `id` property in `Details` component**.

**EDIT: `Details` component is located inside `Article` component and there is no `id...`**

```
const Article = () => (
  <Online>
    <Wrapper>
      <Header>Your article</Header>
      <Details type="articles" />
    </Wrapper>
  </Online>
);

export default Article;
```

It should be a way to pass this `id` property... I'm closer to the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Details component is located inside Article component and there is no
>   id...

Well, you are right. `Details` never get the `match` property. You need to use `withRouter` HOC.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(Details))
```

Or (**not recommended**) drill  props from `Article`

```
const Article = (props) => (
  <Online>
    <Wrapper>
      <Header>Your article</Header>
      <Details type="articles" {...props} />
    </Wrapper>
  </Online>
);
```